# I am trying to print a pattern but its not print it properly

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pattern{

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
        String d = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(d);
        String[] ds = d.split(",");

        for(int i=0;i<ds.length;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<=Integer.parseInt(ds[i]);j++) {
                System.out.print("*");   
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

it print 3 stars in second line but i pass the value 1,4 so it print the output in first line print 1 star and in second line print 4 stars but in output it shows 3 stars in second line not 4 stars how i solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you, it's vital that we know what problem you are facing. This means that we need to know what you are expecting your code to print out and what you are experiencing instead.

Comment: Also having a look at your code: Why do you use `j = i + 1` as your second loop initialization?

Answer (score 0):

j should start at 0 (and condition be strictly <, or 1 and <=):

```
for(int j=0;j<Integer.parseInt(ds[i]);j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String d = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(d);
        String[] ds = d.split(",");
        for(int i=0;i<ds.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<Integer.parseInt(ds[i]);j++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to change your inner loop, the value of `j` should start from `0` and not from `i+1` and the condition of the loop should be `j<Integer.parseInt(ds[i])`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pattern
{
    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String d = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(d);
        String[] ds = d.split(",");
        for(int i=0;i<ds.length;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=Integer.parseInt(ds[i]);j++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Update the variable `j` to `1` instead of `i+1`.